# Sorting the Sql table using alias column

Tags: sql-server, sorting

I have a sql select statement which contains some columns that are computed from some other columns or tables. I gave a name for this column using As keyword.

Now, I want to sort this table by the computed column.
I cant use that name for sorting.

Someone please help to sort the sql table using computed column.

Comment: Wrapping it in [] didn't work in the order by?

Comment: What does "I can't use that name for sorting" actually mean? As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) says, "A sort column can be specified as a name or column alias". Can you show your TSQL code and any error messages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

one more option you can use COLUMN INDEX NUMBER in order by as show in follwoing example

```
select ACol,AVal,CAST(ACol as varchar(3)) + aval as 'New' from ABC order by 3
```

this will use 'New' columnd to sort

Answer (score 21):

In older versions of SQL Server, you can define the alias in a subquery:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  col1 + col2 as col3
        from    YourTable
        ) SubQueryAlias
order by
        col3
```

In SQL Server 2008+ you should be able to `order by` an alias without a subquery:

```
select  col1 + col2 as col3
from    YourTable
order by
        col3
```

Comment: It works in SQL Server 2005 and 2000 as well. From [SQL Server 2000 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259187(v=sql.80).aspx) "A sort column can be specified as a name or column alias"